# Как получить данные из intent не зная ключ?

Tags: android

Использую ActivityResultApi для получения изображения из external storage.
Как мне достать данные из возвращяемого интента, если я не знаю ключ?

```
    class GetImageContract : ActivityResultContract<Unit, Bitmap>() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        return intent
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Bitmap? {
        val data = intent?.extras?.get("Dont know")
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, можно проитерироваться по ключам в bundle. Типа так: `intent?.extras?.keySet?.forEach {  }`

Answer (score 0):

Для [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) результат возвращается в `Intent.getData()`, который типа `Uri`, который содержит путь до контента. Т.е. `Bitmap` сразу из intent'а не получить, см. `ContentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`.

Кстати аналогичный контракт уже есть в SDK `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent`.
И получается так:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestGetFileContents = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), resultUri-> {
  // Открываем поток и дальше читаем, сохраняем, получаем bitmap и т.д.,
  // используя ContentResolver.openInputStream(resultUri)
});

requestChooseFile.launch("image/*");
```